# Why use Spring Boot rather than Spring Boot-less?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm confused why should i use Spring Boot for my next project? Is Spring Boot as powerful as Spring Boot-less? Or there is something you can't do with Spring Boot.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Spring Boot is opinionated Spring setup with batteries included. If you use it, you will waste less time on non-features because you will be getting quite a few things for free.  List of advantages that I've observed compared to classical Spring setup (surely there are more, check the Spring Boot website):

- dependency management - versions of commonly used libraries are pre-selected and grouped in different starter POMs that you can include in your project. By selecting one Spring Boot version you are implicitly selecting dozens of dependencies that you would have to otherwise select and harmonize yourself
- auto-configuration - you do not have to manually configure dispatcher servlet, static resource mappings, property source loader, message converters  etc.
- advanced externalized configuration - there is a large list of bean properties that can be configured through application.properties file without touching java or xml config
- "production ready" features - you get health checking, application and jvm metrics, jmx via http and a few more things for free
- runnable jars - you can package your application as a runnable jar with embedded tomcat included so it presents a self-contained deployment unit

I haven't observed any disadvantages, it's just Spring after all. You can build anything that you could build with "vanilla" Spring, only faster.

Comment: Thank you for explanation, but is Spring Boot really used in production (live) project or some fast-prototypes? And why Spring Boot with main method, doesn't like Spring MVC do (in website case)?

Comment: Main method is present so you can run the project directly from jar. You can also build a war (it's easy to select in `pom.xml`) and do a traditional deployment to tomcat or some other standalone servlet containter. From there it works the same way as Spring MVC becuse it *is* Spring MVC.

Comment: Ah i got it. In my mind, there is only one way to deploy a Spring project (via war and upload into tomcat). 
But one thing, why Spring let the users do theirs work manually if there is a Spring Boot and with no extra advantage?

Comment: @YosuaLijantoBinar there are always scenarios when the opinionated Spring setup does not work and you have to customize it. For example, there are lots of companies that require you to deploy on a WebSphere or Weblogic for example. Even though the Spring Boot WAR can be deployed on them, they still include the `WarLauncher` inside the package and it's significantly bigger. But other than that there aren't many reasons why someone wouldn't do it.

Answer (score 6):

Here is my simple explanation:

Without Spring Boot, one will have to put the correct versions of all the dependencies in the build configuration file (e.g. pom.xml) and configure all the beans manually.

This seems like a lot of non-functional task for normal projects. Hence, Spring Boot does these automatically, assuming some conventions. For example, if you just include `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency in your pom.xml, a web application will be automatically configured by assuming default conventions.

What makes it more interesting is that the pieces of the default configuration can be very easily overridden.

Going through a couple of [official guides](https://spring.io/guides) would give more insight on Spring Boot. In summary, unless an application is abnormal enough, people seem to be preferring Spring Boot nowadays.

Coming to power, Spring Boot could be seen as just a configuration layer. So, everything possible in Spring should also be possible using Spring Boot.

Comment: Very nice explanation, so Spring Boot makes a short-cut to develop. But why the program structure is different? e.q. use Spring Boot, there is main method for website case, its different from Spring MVC.

Comment: The structure is the default that Spring Boot provides. Without Spring Boot, one will have to lay one's own structure. As @mzc has explained in his comment, Spring Boot defaults to producing a JAR/WAR with tomcat embedded. Hence the main method. For a web application, Spring MVC would be used in both cases: it would be Spring MVC + Spring Boot + your customization vs Spring MVC + laying out your own structure completely.